# Trying to introduce .netrc file for pip install

Tags: python, linux, authentication, pip, .netrc

Even after placing the .netrc file at the home directory and doing a chown $USER and chmod 600, the pip install asks for user and passowrd. Am I missing anything here so that the .netrc is ignored?
.netrc file is like:

```
   machine https://artifactory_url_to_the_package
   login username
   password pswrd
```

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/authentication/#netrc-support `machine` must be the host, not URL. Try `python -m netrc` to see if it's parsed.

Comment: I edited and made 
machine artifactory-qa1.xxx.xxx.companyname.com

I gave the wrong password in .netrc. Now I have the package installed successfully still. But at the end it asks for username passwword. If I give wrong, it says the credentials not correct. But I can still see package installed @phd

Comment: I"ve added python tag to increase the number of "watchers" to your Q. Delete if you disagree. Good luck.